# Is it true to say the distance between xmin and xmax is always 196 pt in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

By using trials and errors I found xmax is 196 pt in pgfplots, for the example below.
I have the following questions:

1. How to measure accurately the distance between xmax and xmin in pgfplots?
2. Is this distance invariant and always 196 pt?

Below is the code, I put xmin=0 for the sake of simplicity:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=.1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17,aria/.style={
xmin=0,,ymin=0,ymax=1.1,
xtick={1},ytick={1},
axis x line=bottom ,axis y line=left,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[aria,xmax=1]
\draw[red,|-|](axis cs:0,1)--++(196pt,0);
\draw (axis cs:1,0)--(axis cs:1,1);
\end{axis}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-6.5cm]
\begin{axis}[aria,xmax=10]
\draw[red,|-|](axis cs:0,1)--++(196pt,0);
\draw (axis cs:10,0)--(axis cs:10,1);
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Aria, as you can read in the duplicate question the correct answer is, that with the default settings the `width` of the box (excluding the labels) is 195pt. So you were pretty close.

Comment: Unfortunately your first question is unclear (to me). Please specify "origin": Do you mean the (0,0) coordinate within the `axis` or the (0,0) coordinate in the `tikzpicture` environment? And please also state what your purpose is to know this value. Knowing your ultimate goal we maybe are able to provide another/more easy way to achieve that goal.

Comment: Origin I meant (0,0)

Comment: Regarding your second question the answer most likely is no. For that e.g. add/adapt the following stuff first alone and then in combination: `xmin=-2`, `width=100pt`. (To show the end of your red line you should also add `clip=false` to your `aria/.style`.)

Comment: My goal was to know the length to put nodes in more accurate locations

Comment: Yes, but in which of the two coordinate systems: `axis cs` (= PGFPlots) or `cs` (TikZ)?

Comment: Pgfplots was meant

Comment: Could you edit your question and show (some simplified) code you already have with the result were could add on top a sketch of what you want to achieve? Because "shifting" nodes could most likely be done much easier ...

Comment: Then the answer is _no_ as you will see when you test the stuff I mentioned in [this previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624328/is-it-true-to-say-xmax-is-always-196-pt-in-pgfplots?noredirect=1#comment1558530_624328).

Comment: If you agree it would even be better to delete this question and add a brand new one. This would avoid others to read through all the then most likely unrelated comments.